# scala get first key from seq of map

Tags: scala

In scala, I know the mySeq is an array of Map object and the array only has one element. then I want to get first key of this element. Why it doesn't work ? it gave me error:  `value keySet is not a member of (Int, String)`

code:

```
val mySeq: Seq[(Int, String)] = ... 
        val aMap = mySeq(0)
        val firstKey = aMap.keySet.head
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually a `Seq` of tuples:

```
val aTuple = mySeq(0)
val firstKey = aTuple._1
```

To declare a `Seq` or maps, you'd use:

```
val mySeq: Seq[Map[Int, String]] = ...
```

But note that it doesn't make much sense to get the *first* key of a map, since maps are usually *unordered* by design.

Comment: oh, if I want to define a seq of Map object how it looks like ?

Comment: @user1615666: added that